# how to get copy file progress

Tags: c#

I have a code , but I do not how can I find copy file progress . what should I do to recive file copy progress ?

```
public sealed class FileRoutines
{
    public static void CopyFile(FileInfo source, FileInfo destination)
    {
        CopyFile(source, destination, CopyFileOptions.None);
    }

    public static void CopyFile(FileInfo source, FileInfo destination, 
        CopyFileOptions options)
    {
        CopyFile(source, destination, options, null);
    }

    public static void CopyFile(FileInfo source, FileInfo destination, 
        CopyFileOptions options, CopyFileCallback callback)
    {
        CopyFile(source, destination, options, callback, null);
    }

    public static void CopyFile(FileInfo source, FileInfo destination, 
        CopyFileOptions options, CopyFileCallback callback, object state)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (destination == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destination");
        if ((options & ~CopyFileOptions.All) != 0) 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("options");

        new FileIOPermission(
            FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, source.FullName).Demand();
        new FileIOPermission(
            FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, destination.FullName).Demand();

        CopyProgressRoutine cpr = callback == null ? 
            null : new CopyProgressRoutine(new CopyProgressData(
                source, destination, callback, state).CallbackHandler);

        bool cancel = false;
        if (!CopyFileEx(source.FullName, destination.FullName, cpr, 
            IntPtr.Zero, ref cancel, (int)options))
        {
            throw new IOException(new Win32Exception().Message);
        }
    }

    private class CopyProgressData
    {
        private FileInfo _source = null;
        private FileInfo _destination = null;
        private CopyFileCallback _callback = null;
        private object _state = null;

        public CopyProgressData(FileInfo source, FileInfo destination, 
            CopyFileCallback callback, object state)
        {
            _source = source; 
            _destination = destination;
            _callback = callback;
            _state = state;
        }

        public int CallbackHandler(
            long totalFileSize, long totalBytesTransferred, 
            long streamSize, long streamBytesTransferred, 
            int streamNumber, int callbackReason,
            IntPtr sourceFile, IntPtr destinationFile, IntPtr data)
        {
            return (int)_callback(_source, _destination, _state, 
                totalFileSize, totalBytesTransferred);
        }
    }

    private delegate int CopyProgressRoutine(
        long totalFileSize, long TotalBytesTransferred, long streamSize, 
        long streamBytesTransferred, int streamNumber, int callbackReason,
        IntPtr sourceFile, IntPtr destinationFile, IntPtr data);

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern bool CopyFileEx(
        string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName,
        CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine,
        IntPtr lpData, ref bool pbCancel, int dwCopyFlags);
}

public delegate CopyFileCallbackAction CopyFileCallback(
    FileInfo source, FileInfo destination, object state, 
    long totalFileSize, long totalBytesTransferred);

public enum CopyFileCallbackAction
{
    Continue = 0,
    Cancel = 1,
    Stop = 2,
    Quiet = 3
}

[Flags]
public enum CopyFileOptions
{
    None = 0x0,
    FailIfDestinationExists = 0x1,
    Restartable = 0x2,
    AllowDecryptedDestination = 0x8,
    All = FailIfDestinationExists | Restartable | AllowDecryptedDestination
}
```

Comment: The code above originated in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163851.aspx)  and is attached to that article in the archive file NetMatters0502.exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CopyFileCallbackAction callback(
    FileInfo source, FileInfo destination, object state, 
    long totalFileSize, long totalBytesTransferred)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Copied so far {0}%",
      totalBytesTransferred * 100 / totalFileSize);
}

FileRoutines.CopyFile(src, dest, options, callback)
```