# Make sure file got copied successfully using c#

Tags: c#, file, copy, filestream

I am creating an application to back up files from a source directory into a destination directory. I store the files information from the source and destination folders in separate lists then I compare the lists based on their size, date modified etc to see which files need to be copied.

Anyways the point is that I end up with a list of the files that need to be copied and I will like to know how much time is every file taking therefore I have tried the following techniques:

[Technique 1](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CopyFileEx)

[Technique 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3921518/637142)

Thechnique 3 : the regular File.Copy("source....","Destination")

The first two techniques are great because I can see the progress. The problem is that when I copy some files with those techniques, the new file sometimes has different dates. I will like both files to have the same modified date and also the same creation date. Moreover if for whatever reason my program crashes the file that is being copied will be corrupted because I have tried copying a large file ( a file that takes about a minute to get copied in windows) if I exit my program meanwhile the file is being copied the file that is being copied sometimes has the same attributes and the same size so I want to make sure I don't have corrupted files in case my program crashes.

Maybe I should use aether techniques 1 or 2 and then at the end copy the attributes from the source file and assign those to the destination file. I don't know how to do that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered just writing a shell script that calls [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)?  Any time I've had to run backup tasks like this, I just write a script -- robocopy already does the heavy lifting for me, so there's often no need to create a bespoke application.

Answer (score 2):

[FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) has members CreationTime and LastWriteTime that are settable - so you could settle for your preferring techniques and set the dates afterwards if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I have but its long:

I know I can copy the file from the source and then name the file in the destination something else like "fileHasNotBeenCopiedYet" with attributes of hidden then when my program finishes copying the file change the name to the source name and copy the attributes and then latter I know that if a file with that name ("fileHasNotBeenCopiedYet") exists that means that the file is corrupted.